# unable to install passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

i'm trying to set up a ruby on rails environment to run a website app (clocking it)
unfortunely as I'm a kind of newbie lots of stuff going wrong :p

this is what i got when i run /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/bin# ./passenger-install-apache2-module

```
>  * GNU C++ compiler... found at
> /usr/bin/g++  * Curl development
> headers with SSL support... found  *
> OpenSSL development headers... found 
> * Zlib development headers... found  * Ruby development headers... found  *
> OpenSSL support for Ruby... found  *
> RubyGems... found  * Rake... found at
> /usr/bin/rake  * rack... not found  *
> Apache 2... found at /usr/sbin/apache2
> * Apache 2 development headers... found at /usr/bin/apxs2  * Apache
> Portable Runtime (APR) development
> headers... found at
> /usr/bin/apr-1-config  * Apache
> Portable Runtime Utility (APU)
> development headers... found at
> /usr/bin/apu-1-config
```

Ok so i just miss rack, so i do this:

```
gem install rack --source http://chneukirchen.org/releases/gems/
Successfully installed rack-1.2.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rack-1.2.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rack-1.2.1...
```

everyhting looks ok but i still have the same problem
rack is still not found by passenger, how can i solve this ?

other thing I don't understand how to update gem ??

```
# gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    gem update --system is disabled on Debian. RubyGems can be updated using the official Debian repositories by aptitude or apt-get.
```

any help is welcome !

---

I would to follow your how-to but first i need to remove packages installed with aptitude, do you know in this list which ones I need to remove ? this is all the stuff I apt-get since i try to install ruby ...

```
>   aptitude install git-core
>     aptitude install libssl-dev zlib1g-dev build-essential
> mysql-server mysql-client
> libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
> imagemagick libmagick9-dev
> librmagick-ruby librmagick-ruby1.8
> libxslt1-dev
>     aptitude install rubygems
>     aptitude install ruby1.8-dev
>     aptitude install rubygems1.9
>     aptitude install rake
>     aptitude install rubygems
>     aptitude install ruby libzlib-ruby rdoc irb
>     aptitude install rubygems1.9
>     aptitude install libyaml-ruby
>     aptitude install libzlib-ruby 
>     aptitude install  libcurl4-openssl-dev
>     aptitude install libopenssl-ruby 
>     aptitude install apache2-prefork-dev
>     aptitude install libapr1-dev
>     aptitude install ibaprutil1-dev
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first mistake was installing RubyGems from apt. I cover the proper way to set this all up in [my Ubuntu, Ruby, RVM, Rails and You post](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/). Give that a go and see if that helps you get passenger running.

Comment: thanks, it seems that all my problems came from apt...But I'm not sure what to do exactly to solve this, I remove rubygems with aptitude and I'm planning to install it from the source took here: http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126 ...Will that do the trick? or should I remove ruby as well ? ruby -v ->ruby 1.6.8 ...Do i need RVM ?